# Error generating pdf from QGIS web client under Windows?

Tags: print-composer, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

If I push the print button on the toolbar, I get the menu which works fine. However, when I try to print the map, the pdf doesn't generate.

That's why I look into firebug and I get following comment:

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - ...localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/qgis-web-client-master/projects/demo.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&TRANSPARENT=true&SRS=EPSG:3857&DPI=300&TEMPLATE=test&map0:extent=1511664.8,6839757.4,1525015.2,6846582.6&map0:rotation=0&map0:scale=75000&map0:grid_interval_x=5000&map0:grid_interval_y=5000&LAYERS=Hausnummer%2Cinfrastruktur%2CGeb%C3%A4ude&OPACITIES=255%2C255%2C255"

---

Apache access log give this response:

> "POST /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/qgis-web-client-master/projects/demo.qgs& HTTP/1.1" 200 798
>
> "GET /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/qgis-web-client-master/projects/demo.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&TRANSPARENT=true&SRS=EPSG:3857&DPI=300&TEMPLATE=test&map0:extent=1509449.3,6838361.9,1527249.8,6847462.1&map0:rotation=0&map0:scale=100000&map0:grid_interval_x=5000&map0:grid_interval_y=5000&LAYERS=Hotel%20-%20Ferienhaus%2CCamping&OPACITIES=255%2C255 HTTP/1.1" 500 538

---

If I manually change the `FORMAT=pdf` to `FORMAT=png` it runs correctly.

Does somebody now what I have to change so I can export a pdf?

I'm using Windows.

Comment: Please post the server log. Otherwise we can only guess. The umlaut in "Gebäude" could be a problem.

Comment: i added the apache access log. I hope it is the correct log

Comment: Isn't there also an error log?

Comment: no i doesn't get a error. only in the firebug

Comment: i found out, if i change the format=png it works correct. Does somebody now what i have to change for pdf. I using  Windows

Comment: I've got the same problem... Can anyone tell me where can I change the pdf in png in the code? I mean not once, but for all maps...
Where/how can I disable 'fit to page'? Thanks!

Comment: in the WebGISInit.js |  printUrl = printURI + 'SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=image/png&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&TRANSPARENT=true';  |But I'm still looking for a solution for PDF

Comment: The error log only gives out: Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi,

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, and discovered that when the print selection window within the client contained polygons that had a fill Style that used a point pattern fill, that the PDF would never generate.

As a test, try to generate a PDF that only contains point and line objects and see if it works.

If yes, then try to generate a PDF that also contains a polygon feature.
If it causes the PDF generation problem, then I would say that your polygons are the problem.

Obviously if you have several polygon layers with different styles you will have to test them individually to identify the culprit.

Comment: i tested to generate a PDF with points.

I get the same error i described above. 
At the window is only the alternativetext shown. printingObjectDataAlternativeString1--Your browser doesn't support ..

Comment: nobody any idea ?